# Displaying parse string as label issue

Tags: iphone, ios, parsing, uilabel

I've got a label which is displayed in a subview. I got the text of the label from a NSString on parse. However, I tried to display the text but it doesnt seems to work. There is no text displayed.

Here is my code. Please let me know if you know how to solve this:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"myapp"];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"myId"
                             block:^(PFObject *textu, NSError *error) {
                                 if (!error) {

                                     CGRect infoLabelRect = CGRectMake(10, 250, 260, 350);
                                     UILabel *infoLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:infoLabelRect];


                                     NSString *text = [textu objectForKey:@"newstext"];
                                     UIFont *font = nil;
                                     CGFloat points = 17;
                                     CGFloat maxHeight = infoLabel.frame.size.height;
                                     CGFloat textHeight;
                                     do {
                                         font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:points];
                                         CGSize size = CGSizeMake(infoLabelRect.size.width, 100000);
                                         CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:size lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
                                         textHeight = textSize.height;
                                         points -= 1;
                                     } while (textHeight > maxHeight);
                                     infoLabel.font = font;
                                     infoLabel.numberOfLines = 9;

                                     infoLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                                     infoLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
                                     infoLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                                     infoLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                                     infoLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);

                                     [infoLabel sizeToFit];
                                     [contentView addSubview:infoLabel];


                                 } else {
                                     // Log details of our failure
                                     CGRect infoLabelRect = CGRectMake(10, 250, 260, 350);
                                     UILabel *infoLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:infoLabelRect];

                                     infoLabel.text = @"Connection error!";

                                 }
                             }];
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something....  If there is no error, where do you set the text of the label?

Comment: In the code you gave I don't see that you assign your infoLabel your text retrieved from parse.
Plus your logic with determining font size for infoLabel is not quite clear to me. Why don't you just set initial font, minimumScaleFactor and assign 0 to number of lines. This way font size and number of lines will be determined automatically.

Comment: NSString *text = [textu objectforkey....];

Comment: No, that's creating a local variable that has no connection to the label.

Comment: you see below at the cgsize... [text sizeWithFront....]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first part of code doesn't contain assignment to text

```
infoLabel.text = text; // or @"Some text" for testing
```

Your last part of code only creates UILabel, but doesn't add it as subview

```
UILabel *infoLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:infoLabelRect];
infoLabel.text = @"Connection error!";
[contentView addSubview:infoLabel];
```

Comment: Yes it was the first thing you wrote